# Do people agree on what dx is in Riemann integration?

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, riemann-integration, differential

I've been rather curious about what the official rigorous understanding of the dx term in a Riemann integral is. Of course, we could use the formal definition of a Riemann integral but I have seen on Wikipedia other proposed ways of defining the differential of some function (we'll call x), dx. The classic high school teacher approach is to say it's a "very small change in x", or rather a small change in a linear approximation of x. However, as someone who studies differential geometry, I am wondering how this can be interpreted as the exterior derivative of a function x, in which dx is a 1-form. Do we then reinterpret $\int{f(x)}\,dx$ as being the integral of a 1-form? And how then can we consider a 1-form to be a "small change in x"?

Comment: It is **Riemann.** Not “Reimann” or “Reimman”. [Georg Friedrich Bernhard Riemann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernhard_Riemann)

Comment: nor "Ramanujan" ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @JetChung I thought it was "Weemoon"

Comment: You may understand integration as a kind of inverse process of differentiation. Given a function $f(x),$ we can calculate its differential to get $f'(x)dx.$ Hence given a differential $g(x)dx,$ we may seek the function that has this differential. If you think of functions on intervals of the real axis as smooth analogues of sequences, then by comparing to the process of calculating differences and summing them back to get the original sequence, you can see that from $g(x)dx$ we get back $G(a)+\int g(x)dx=G(x),$ where I have allowed common notational abuses. In all of this the quantity $dx$...

Comment: ...is just the differential of the quantity $x,$ namely an infinitely small change in $x,$ which has a definite meaning (thanks to nonstandard analysis).

Answer (score 4):

This question has been asked a million times on this site in one form or another. But I suppose it can’t hurt to answer it again since it is so natural a question but also so typically badly answered.

The short answer to your title question is yes: there is agreement about what the $dx$ means — but only once you get precise about exactly what kind of integral you’re talking about. The one-dimensional baby’s-first-integral in $\mathbb{R}$ can be interpreted in many different ways that only come apart once you move to integration in more general spaces.

If you’re thinking about $\int_{[a,b]}f dx$ as giving the integral of a density $f$ over an *unoriented* interval $[a,b]$, then $dx$ generally denotes a **measure**. Example: if $f$ measures mass per unit length over a rod, then the integral gives the mass of the rod. This generalizes easily to higher-dimensional Euclidean spaces: the “area element” $dA$ and the “volume element” $dV$ are really measures. In differential geometry you want to integrate such things not just over subsets of Euclidean space but over abstract manifolds. In that case you don’t have a measure, but you do have the differential geometric analog of a measure called a **density**.

If, however, you’re thinking about $\int_a^bfdx$ as giving the integral of $f$ over the *oriented* interval $[a,b]$, then $dx$ generally denotes a **differential form**. Example: if $f$ measures the rate of change of some quantity as a function of $x$, then the integral gives the total change in the quantity as $x$ ranges *from* $a$ *to* $b$ — that’s the fundamental theorem, which is just a special case of Stokes theorem, which is a theorem that depends crucially on orientations and thus on differential forms. There is a connection between differential forms and densities, however. Densities are in some sense the natural objects to integrate: they’re defined whether you have an orientation or not. You can only integrate a differential form if you have an orientation, by contrast — and indeed the whole point of the orientation is that it provides enough information to turn the differential form into a density, which can then be integrated.

If you reject all this seeming abstract nonsense and insist on an answer in the case of the most familiar, calculus 101 one-dimensional Riemann integral of a bounded real function $f$ on $[a,b]$, the answer is that the $dx$ is literally meaningless, a mere piece of suggestive notation. The value of the integral, if it exists, is solely a function of $f$ and of $[a,b]$; the best notation to emphasize this is $\int_{[a,b]}f$, with no $dx$ at all.

Comment: For more detail you may wish to read Terry Tao’s “Differential Forms and Integration” at https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/preprints/forms.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The title doesn't really match the question, but perhaps it suffices to say that $d x$ is a 1-form which is the exterior derivative of the function $x$, i.e. the identity function on $\mathbb{R}^1$.

This function takes $x$ to $x$, hence the name $x$; compare e.g. when we write $\sin(x)$ for the function that takes $x$ to $\sin(x)$.  (These are both abuses of notation; the latter should just be called $\sin$ when we're talking about the function, while the former should be called ${\rm id}$ or something.)